# Comment pourrait-on dire en français « at the end of the day » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

L'expression « *at the end of the day* » en anglais s'emploie pour exprimer le fait que les mots suivants sont définitifs, ou les derniers d'un débat.  Par exemple :

> *These acts are indefensible.  At the end of the day, you're either with us or with the terrorists.*

Est-il correct d'utiliser la traduction littérale « à la fin du jour », ou existe-t-il une autre phrase avec le même sens que l'anglais ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

La traduction littérale n'a pas de sens.

Par contre on peut éventuellement utiliser une formule similaire sémantiquement : *"au final"*.

Selon la tournure, on peut utiliser *"en fin de compte"* ou *"au bout du compte"* (dans cet exemple précis je trouve que ça ne sonne pas très bien).

D'autres tournures me semblent correspondre, mais ne vont pas du tout avec l'exemple : *"tout compte fait"*, *"tout bien pesé"*...

Comment: Je trouve *au bout du compte* tout à fait approprié pour l'exemple.

Comment: Ok. :) Le sens est correct, mais je trouve que le résultat _"Au bout du compte, soit vous êtes de notre côté soit vous êtes du côté des terroristes."_ est étrange. D'un autre côté la citation originale est déjà étrange.

Comment: Spontanément j'aurais répondu _au bout du compte_ aussi.

Comment: *Au bout du compte*, *En fin de compte*, c'est très bien aussi!

Comment: _Finalement_, il ne manque quasi rien à cette réponse.

Comment: En passant: [tout compte fait](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/French/linguistics/789102-tout_compte_fait_tous_comptes_faits.html) — et le [ngram correspondant](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=tout+compte+fait%2Ctous+comptes+faits&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3) est sans appel.

Comment: Celui-ci me plaît bien aussi :) http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=tout+compte+fait%2Cen+d%C3%A9finitive&year_start=1800&year_end=2011&corpus=7&smoothing=3

Comment: @Joubarc: Merci. Cela dit je ne comprends plus la signification de "tout compte fait" écrit au singulier.

Comment: @Julien si tu veux, je connais un bon site où on peut [poser](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ce genre de questions.

Comment: Il faudra que je teste ! :-)

Answer (score 21):

La traduction littérale *à la fin de la journée* ne fonctionne pas en français. J’utiliserais plutôt la tournure *au final*, ou *en définitive*:

> Ces actes sont indéfendables. Au final, vous êtes soit avec nous, soit avec les terroristes

Ou encore :

> Ces actes sont indéfendables. En définitive, si vous n'êtes pas avec nous, vous êtes avec les terroristes

Comment: _"En définitive"_ marche très très bien effectivement.

Answer (score 5):

« À la fin du jour » ne sera jamais compris dans le même sens que l'anglais.

Je pense que « au final », « à la fin » ou « finalement » expriment ce que tu veux dire.

> Au final, tu es avec ou contre nous.

Answer (score 3):

"At the end of the day" correspond à "en fin de compte" ou encore "au bout du compte".

Answer (score 1):

"Au final" est la tournure la plus courante à l'oral, mais certains la considèrent comme une négligence à l'écrit, à tort ou à raison. "En définitive" est une tournure plus soutenue et qui n'a pas ce problème. "Finalement" peut aussi fonctionner. Sinon, il y a aussi le très soutenu "en dernière analyse" qui est sans doute la formulation la plus éloquente (et sonne un peu philosophique).

Answer (score -1):

« at the end of the day » ne s'emploie pas vraiment pour affirmer que les mots qui suivent sont les derniers; on devrait dire plutôt qu'ils sont les plus importants, mais cela n'équivaut encore qu'à mentionner le squelette en négligeant la chair, si l'on peut dire.

Il me semble fortement que le contexte de la phrase de la question,

> « These acts are indefensible. At the end of the day, you're either with us or with the terrorists. »,

ne convient pas du tout à une utilisation de cette expression. Une expression acceptable dans ce contexte est « there is no middle way ».

Ne jamais faire la traduction inverse « En fin de compte, est-tu avec nous ou contre nous ? → At the end of the day, are you with us or against us? », elle est fausse.

1. « au final » me semble à peine acceptable, trop populaire, mais à la rigueur on peut faire dire à ce terme « at the end of the day ».

   2. Pour des situations courantes trois possibilités sont acceptables :

   en définitive, en fin de compte (fam.), tous comptes faits

Cependant il ne faut pas négliger la possibilité de l'introduction d'une proposition de remplacement basée sur le contexte. (voir exemple ci-dessous)

3. L'utilisation de « en dernière analyse », qui ne se situe pas au niveau d'un choix de registre, ne convient pas en cela que cette expression implique une assez étroite dépendance sur des faits précis et une conclusion plus ou moins inéluctable; on peut profiter de cette remarque et continuer par essayer de cerner le sens plus profond de cette expression; ce qu'exprime « at the end of the day » c'est le résultat  relativement ineffectif des efforts de l'être humain à contrôler les forces qui donnent forme à sa vie, c'est son impuissance malgré l'esprit prévoyant qu'il aura pu appliquer à la résolution de ses problèmes d'en venir à bout d'une façon suffisamment satisfaisante, c'est la réalisation qu'il n'y a pas de recette miracle et qu'il y a un prix à payer. Il n'y a pas dans les contextes de son utilisation l'existence de relations de cause à effet bien déterminées.

ex : You have wonderful grammar books to explain to you the syntax of the language, the dictionaries that are available to you provide you with the key to the meaning of a multitude of words, all kinds of other ressources such as phrase books give you more information than you'll ever be able to use, but at the end of day, when comes the time to write your first sentence nothing can take the place of a good ten years' reading the language now and then.

…mais quels que soient les moyens didactiques dont vous disposez,…

Comment: Un peu présomptueux de votre part, je trouve, de reprendre l'OP sur son anglais !  Si encore vous aviez raison, ça pourrait passer, mais ce n'est pas le cas.