# Tout compte fait, ou tous comptes faits?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, orthographe, pluriel, origine-ou-raison

L'[on me reprenait sur la graphie de « *Tous comptes faits* »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/comment-pourrait-on-dire-en-francais-at-the-end-of-the-day/1011#1011), arguant [chiffres à l'appui](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=tout%20compte%20fait,tous%20comptes%20faits&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3), que la graphie correcte est au singulier : « *Tout compte fait* ».

Au pluriel je comprends l'expression (une fois que tous les comptes sont faits), mais pas au singulier. D'où ma question : pourquoi l'expression est-elle au singulier ?

Question subsidiaire, la graphie au pluriel est-elle correcte, ou est-elle injustifiée ?

Comment: L'on s'excuse d'avoir été la cause d'un tel tourment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Je ne comprends pas ton incompréhension. Un peu à la manière de « chaque, » « tout X » au singulier peut vouloir dire « tous les Xs » (Le TLF, dans son sens C, appelle ça « l'idée de distributivité exhaustive »).

L'exemple qui me venait en tête (d'ailleurs cité par le TLF) est « Tout condamné à mort aura la tête tranchée. » On peut aussi penser à des lois physiques « Tout corps plongé dans un liquide... »

Il me paraît donc logique de dire « tout compte fait, » et c'est pour moi synonyme de « tous les comptes étant faits. »

Ça me fait également penser au quantificateur universel « ∀ » qui se lit « pour tout » mais ça c'est peut-être juste ma perversion personnelle...

La version au pluriel est également citée dans le TLF. On peut donc dire qu'elle est acceptée :-)

Comment: +1 Pour la math-geekerie.

Comment: Merci, je suis convaincu. :)

Comment: Je pense que la même réflexion peu s'appliquer à "De toute façon..." , que j'ai longtemps écrit "De toutes façons" en me disant que c'était la forme plus courte de "De toutes les façons..."

Comment: Pas du tout le même principe. On établit des comptes et chacun se doit d'être fait avant de parvenir à une conclusion, alors que «Tout condamné à mort» ou «Tout corps plongé dans un liquide» établit une règle pour chacun, avant même que ne survienne l'évènement. Mettre les deux en parallèle serait comme de dire que peu importe le compte fait, la conclusion en sera la même. J'aime mieux le parallèle avec «Toute honte bue», mentionné dans une autre réponse et bien plus exact.

Answer (score 7):

C'est parce que l'expression ne veut pas dire "une fois que tous les comptes sont faits", mais "une fois que tout le compte est fait".

La confusion vient de la syntaxe archaïque de l'expression.
"Tout" veut dire la totalité du compte.

On trouve la même structure archaïque dans l'expression "Toute honte bue". C'est exactement la même structure Toute honte bue/Tout compte fait.

Answer (score 4):

J'ai trouvé une réponse sur [cette page](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/French/linguistics/789102-tout_compte_fait_tous_comptes_faits.html#1961718e).

> « Tout compte fait » est une locution adverbiale [...] Selon le contexte, on peut remplacer [...] par « en définitive », « en fin de compte » ou « finalement ».
>
> « Tous comptes faits » signifie « les comptes une fois faits ».

Les deux expressions sont donc correctes.

Comment: Un peu de développement serait bienvenu.

Comment: Sur Stack exchange, l'usage est de reproduire (lorsque c'est autorisé) ou de résumer la réponse, en complément d'un hyperlien qui cite la source.

Comment: ça donne l'emploi de l'expression, mais ça ne répond pas vraiment à la question de savoir pourquoi on utilise "tous" au lieu de "tout".

Comment: Je m'aperçois que j'avais supprimé ma conclusion, et donc ma réponse est encore moins précise. Je vous pris de m'excuser.

Answer (score 3):

Je pense que l'on peut comprendre « tout compte fait » comme :

> Une fois que l'ensemble du compte est fait

Cela se rapproche d'expressions comme « avoir son compte » ou « au bout du compte ».

Answer (score 1):

Tout à fait (et non "tous à faits") d'accord avec Feelew: "Tout" au sens de "chacun" n'est pas pertinent en l'espèce.
Et "une fois que tout le compte est fait" sonne assez mal, non?
J'en resterais à "tous comptes faits", qui semble plus logique que la formule au singulier.